# Parsing the html meta tag with jsoup library

Tags: java, html, html-parsing, jsoup

Just started exploring the Jsoup library as i will use it for one of my projects. I tried googling but i could not find the exact answer that can help me. Here is my problem, i have an html file with meta tags like below

```
<meta content="this is the title value" name="d.title">
<meta content="this is the description value" name="d.description">
<meta content="language is french" name="d.language">
```

And a java pojo like so,

```
public class Example {
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String language;

    public Example() {}

    // setters and getters go here
}
```

Now i want to parse the html file and extract the d.title content value and store in Example.title and d.description value of "content" and store in Example.description and so on and so forth.

What i have done by reading jsoup cookbook is somethink like,

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("test.html");
Elements metaTags = doc.getElementsByTag("meta");

for (Element metaTag : metaTags) {
    String content = metaTag.attr("content");
    String content = metaTag.attr("name");
}
```

what that will do is walk through all meta tags get the value of their "content" and "name" attributes, but what i want is to get the value of "content" attribute whose "name" attribute is say "d.title" so that i can store it in Example.title

**Update:** @P.J.Meisch answer below actually sovles the problem but that is too much code for my liking(was trying to avoid doing the exact same thing). I mean i was thinking it could be possible to do something like

String title = metaTags.getContent("d.title")

where d.title is the value of the "name" attribute
That way it will reduce the lines of code, i have not found such a method but maybe that is because am still new to jsoup thats why i asked. But if such a method does not exist(which would be nice if it did cuz it makes life easier) i would just go with P.J.Meisch said.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

ok, all the code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("test.html");
Elements metaTags = doc.getElementsByTag("meta");

Example ex = new Example();

for (Element metaTag : metaTags) {
  String content = metaTag.attr("content");
  String name = metaTag.attr("name");

  if("d.title".equals(name)) {
    ex.setTitle(content);
  }
  if("d.description".equals(name)) {
    ex.setDescription(content);
  }
  if("d.language".equals(name)) {
    ex.setLanguage(content);
  }
}
```

Comment: ok, i understand your answer now. Thanks. But i was hoping i would not resort to something like that. I'll update my question to reflect what i actually want. :)

Comment: updated my question, can you take a look and see if what i want is possible?

Comment: i first approved your other answer that uses a map, but I realized that, it would not work well, because, the html files am processing has name attributes that appear more than once(like d.contributor can appear multiple times), and if i use a map to store them, the map will store only the last one since it cannot have the same key referring to different objects. So i just went along with this

Comment: the map has as keys only the name attributes of the meta tags and not of other tags that have name elements, so that should work

Comment: what i am saying some name attributes have the same value, like there can be more than one d.contributor as a name. and the map stores as keys the name attribute which in this case is "d.contributor" which occurs 3 times hence the map will only store the last one

Answer (score 4):

to answer your updated question: this is not possible with jsoup, as the jsoup document just reflects the xml/dom structure of the html document. You will have to iterate yourself over the metas, but you could do something like this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("test.html");

Map<String, String> metas = new HashMap<>();
Elements metaTags = doc.getElementsByTag("meta");

for (Element metaTag : metaTags) {
  String content = metaTag.attr("content");
  String name = metaTag.attr("name");
  metas.put(name, content);
}

Example ex = new Example();
ex.setTitle(metas.get("d.title"));
ex.setDescription(metas.get("d.description"));
ex.setLanguage(metas.get("d.language"));
```

Comment: thanks. this is the closest to what i want. But it would be nice if jsoup had that feature, since it opensource, i'll try to see if i can get it in :)

Answer (score 1):

Using the right specific library simplifies everything

Check out my library for parsing meta tag content

[poshjosh/bcmetaselector](https://github.com/poshjosh/bcmetaselector)

```
package com.bc.meta.selector;

import com.bc.meta.selector.htmlparser.AttributeContextHtmlparser;
import com.bc.meta.selector.util.SampleConfigPaths;
import com.bc.meta.ArticleMetaNames;
import com.bc.meta.impl.ArticleMetaNameIsMultiValue;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.function.BiFunction;
import org.json.simple.JSONValue;
import org.htmlparser.Parser;
import org.htmlparser.Node;
import org.htmlparser.Tag;

public class ReadMe {

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

        final BiFunction<String, Node, String> nodeContentExtractor =
                (prop, node) -> node instanceof Tag ? ((Tag)node).getAttributeValue("content") : null;

        final SelectorBuilder<Node, String, Object> builder = Selector.builder();

        final Selector<Node> selector = builder.filter()
                .attributeContext(new AttributeContextHtmlparser(false))
                .configFilePaths(SampleConfigPaths.APP_ARTICLE_LIST)
                .jsonParser((reader) -> (Map)JSONValue.parse(reader))
                .propertyNames(ArticleMetaNames.values())
                .back()
                .multipleValueTest(new ArticleMetaNameIsMultiValue())
                .nodeConverter(nodeContentExtractor)
                .build();

        final Parser parser = new Parser();

        final String url = "https://edition.cnn.com/2018/06/21/africa/noura-hussein-asequals-intl/index.html";

        parser.setURL(url);

        Iterator<Node> nodes = parser.elements().iterator();

        final Map map = selector.selectAsMap(nodes, ArticleMetaNames.values());

        System.out.println("Printing meta tags data for: " + url + "\n" + map);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you assign the value of both attributes to the same variable named content. Assign the name attribute to a `name`variable and compare that to your desired value of 'd.title'.

Comment: how would i know the desired value of d.title. the html files are not produced by me so i would not know before hand the value of 'd.title'